# How can I find removed apps?

Tags: applications, data-transfer

Is there any way that I can download apps that I removed last week? (I can't remember the names of them)

Comment: You should specify how you got the apps and on which device. Mac? iPhone? From the internet? From Mac App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've downloaded them on the Mac App Store.
- You can find them again in the "Purchased" tab inside Mac App Store.

If you downloaded them outside of the Mac App Store.
- They might be in your specified "Downloads" folder, if you haven't deleted them from that.

If you downloaded them on your iPhone/iPad.
- You can find your previously purchased apps on these devices either on iTunes or in App Store on your device. Go to the "Updates" tab and choose "Purchased".

Comment: Thank you, it worked and I meant on my iPhone. :) It took such long time to load the list, is there any way to delete them, and not only hide them?

Comment: You can't delete apps from the purchased tab. Remember to accept the answer, if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks again, i can't find the accept button...Or have i done that now?

Comment: Yes, you have accepted it now.

Comment: You can delete them as of December or so. on an iOS device, swipe left or right on an item you want to delete. In iTunes or the Mac App Store, hover over the app icon and click the X button that appears.